# Neat - what do these (multiple) traceback error messages tell me?

Tags: neat

I was installing neat and came across these traceback errors (most recent call last):

```
9: from /Users/jgattus/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.3/bin/neat:23:in `<main>'
8: from /Users/jgattus/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.3/bin/neat:23:in `load'
7: from /Users/jgattus/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/neat-4.0.0/bin/neat:5:in `<top (required)>'
6: from /Users/jgattus/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
5: from /Users/jgattus/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
4: from /Users/jgattus/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
3: from /Users/jgattus/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2: from /Users/jgattus/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/neat-4.0.0/lib/neat/generator.rb:12:in `install'
1: from /Users/jgattus/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/neat-4.0.0/lib/neat/generator.rb:51:in `neat_files_already_exist?'
```

/Users/jgattus/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/neat-4.0.0/lib/neat/generator.rb:56:in `install_path': uninitialized constant Neat::Generator::Pathname (NameError)

I tried using `neat install` along with `neat install --path` but no luck. I'm unsure if it's a bug or I am somehow mucking it up.

```
$ gem install neat
$ neat install
```

I expect neat to install without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The tracebacks must be related to my specific ruby installation. I ran a clean install of Ruby and Rails using the guide [Install Rails](http://installrails.com).  I could then install Neat to my project successfully.